# Can't truncate a number with Python

Tags: python, string, numbers, format

I keep finding multiple and seemingly wrong suggestions for how to truncate numbers with Python 3. I need to print 2 numbers, to two decimal places. My code to do that does not work and Python throws: `Unknown format code for type 'str'`

```
for row in reader:
    print("Time Stamp: %s - Temperature °C: %s - Humidity: %%: %s" % (row[0], "{:.2f}".format(row[1]), "{:.2f}".format(row[2])))
```

I have tried changing the `%s` to `%f` but a similar error. How do I truncate/trim to 2 decimal places?

Comment: truncate and not round? what do you want printed for 1.09999999?

Comment: It looks like the number you want to 'truncate' is actually a string.  Are you sure it is a `float`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have strings in your list. Simply convert them to float before formatting:

```
for row in reader:
    print("Time Stamp: %s - Temperature °C: %.2f - Humidity: %%: %.2f" % (row[0], float(row[1]), float(row[2])))
```

Comment: Daniel, your code isn't truncating, it is rounding. The `%.2f` rounds instead of truncating!

Answer (score 3):

I think your error `Unknown format code for type str`  means that your values in `row` are not numbers but strings. You should convert it using `float` first.

```
 for row in reader:
    rowvals = [float(x) for x in row]
    print ....
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the variable is a float or int by doing something like this:

```
a = int(a)
```

or for a float

```
b = float(b)
```

For an array,

```
val = [float(i) for i in val]
```

From here, there are two options.

## 1

```
a = <yournumber>
print("{0:.3}".format(a))
```

This will round so 2.618 would return 2.62.

## 2

```
a = <yournumber>
print("{0:.2f}".format(a))
```

Which will just give you something like 2.62 also when 2.618 is put in.